# How to avoid mousePressEvent - left click to call paintEvent in PyQt

Tags: pyqt, focus, paintevent, mousepress

In this program below, I am testing the affect of mousePressEvent:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, Qt, QtCore


class Test(QtGui.QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QFrame.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(30,30,500, 500)
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e=None): 
        print "paintEvent"
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.drawRect(30,30,80,80)
        qp.end()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            print "mousePressEvent- Right"
        else:
            print "mousePressEvent- Left"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Test()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I see that in the first left-click, the frame's paintEvent is called. Is this because when the frame get the focus, it need to be repainted? I wonder if there is any way to **avoid paintEvent to be called and every drawing in the frame still intact**. The reason is because in my real program, the paintEvent is really heavy, I want to run it as less times as possible.

If that is not possible, is there a way to avoid the frame getting focus when left-click on that?

Comment: Yes, the paint can happen when the focus changes (and not for the actual clicks). The obvious thing would be to have a scene_was_changed flag that says whether a redraw is actually needed or not. To actually change the calling of paintEvent, you could intercept the focusIn and focusOut events.

Comment: If you want to reject event then you can use event.ignore()

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether there are platform-specific differences at play here, but when I try the example code on Linux, there is no `paintEvent` when clicking on the frame.

This is not surprising really, because, by default, the QFrame is not configured to accept focus of any kind. To get the example to work, I had to explicitly set the [focus policy](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop), like this:

```
class Test(QtGui.QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QFrame.__init__(self)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
```

But maybe the defaults are somehow different on other platforms, and so, to explicitly prevent the frame getting the focus, you might need to do this:

```
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
```